# Mysql insert query

Tags: mysql

With Mysql tables like

```
table_main
    id
    firstname
    lastname

table_type
    id
    table_main_id
    table_type_id

table_type
    id
    typename
```

can a single sql insert query be contructed to run once with

```
fields: firstname, lastname, typename
values: john,doe,mytypename
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT INTO table_name (firstname, lastname, typename)
VALUES (john, doe, mytypename)

won't work because you're trying to insert into multiple tables at once.

My suggestion would be to make a stored procedure that takes arguments firstname, lastname, and typename and then does the proper inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but you can create a **procedure** and then call with it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html